# how can I fix this "Chinese garbled character" problem?

Tags: java, hibernate, character-encoding

After I started a SpringMVC project in JetBrain IDEA, some of the console information appeared as Chinese garbled characters, as shown in the screen shot below:

[image: Stack trace]

Here is that stack trace in text form:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 鏁版嵁搴撲腑宸插瓨鍦ㄥ悕涓� 'Pro_Plan' 鐨勫璞°��
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:662) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.statement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:2993) ~[druid-1.2.20.jar:?]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterAdapter.statement_execute(FilterAdapter.java:2483) ~[druid-1.2.20.jar:?]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterEventAdapter.statement_execute(FilterEventAdapter.java:182) ~[druid-1.2.20.jar:?]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.statement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:2991) ~[druid-1.2.20.jar:?]
    at com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.StatementProxyImpl.execute(StatementProxyImpl.java:143) ~[druid-1.2.20.jar:?]
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledStatement.execute(DruidPooledStatement.java:635) ~[druid-1.2.20.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    ... 77 more
```

The operating system is WIN 11, the encoding is GBK, and the project startup container is Tomcat. Because the default encoding of Notepad is GBK, I configured the output encoding format in logging.properties as GBK.

How can I make this information appear properly?

I tried to change the file encoding configration of IDEA, but the project could not be started because some of the packages referenced by the project require UTF-8 encoding as a whole. So I keep UTF-8 in the encoding configuration of IDEA.

I also tried to change the output encoding format in logging.properties as UTF-8 for Tomcat. It seemed not useful after I restarted my project and caused new problem that other Chinese info which had appeared normally also became garbled. So I restored the output encoding format to GBK and must keep console encoding format using GBK as the same reason.

It seems that logging information about Hibernate operating when staring project used UTF-8 so it could not appear properly in GBK-encoded console. But why did the other Chinese logging info appear properly ? They also use the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Try `hibernate.connection.CharSet=GBK` and `hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=GBK` and maybe `hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried it and it was not useful.

Comment: Consoles have often problems. UTF-8 encoding is "modern", but not supported by all consoles. Fonts creates problems (consoles expect monospacing, but then we have the double spacing characters which are not consistently handled). Etc.  If it is possible: save to a log file, and use an editor (possibly one which notice updates on the files). Else: a true terminal (outside JetBrain) is better then "build-in" terminal/wrapper, which do much magic, but so it fails often (e.g. if you print "..." or something that may seems a prompt. PS: fill a bug report to them.